# Show that if d(n) is O( f (n)) and e(n) is O(g(n)), then d(n)−e(n) is not necessarily O( f (n)−g(n))

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I  have this question as an assignment in my Java Algorithms class, and i'm aware that d(n)+e(n) is the same as O(f(n)+g(n)). I dont know why the same doesnt apply to subtracting. Can someone help me? I'm lost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d(n) = 2n$ and $e(n) = n$. Then
$$d(n)-e(n) = n.$$
Since $d(n) = O(n)$ and $e(n) = O(n)$, we have that $$f(n) = g(n) = n,$$
so
$$O(f(n)-g(n)) = O(n-n) = O(1),$$
and clearly $$n \neq O(1).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately the question is a [duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30141/98). Please check the answer over there; if you think yours adds something worth keeping, please repost your answer over there. Thanks!